# Flask, change telegram bot token in runtime

Tags: python, flask, telegram

This is how I start the bot now:

```
""" Bot logic """
from flask import request
from shopbot_crm import shopbot_crm_bp
import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot import apihelper
import secrets


from models import db, TgBot

secret = secrets.token_urlsafe(32)
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token', threaded=False)
bot.remove_webhook()
time.sleep(1)
bot.set_webhook(url="https://mywebhook.com/bot_panel/bot/{}".format(secret))
apihelper.ENABLE_MIDDLEWARE = True

@shopbot_crm_bp.route('/bot/{}'.format(secret), methods=["POST"])
def webhook():
    bot.process_new_updates([telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))])
    return "ok", 200


@shopbot_crm_bp.route('/bot/reload', methods=["GET"])
def bot_reload():
    #Can I somehow change the token from here?


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def hello(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello')
```

In my application, the user should be able to change the current token to the bot.

**Question**:
How can I change this token to another and re-create the webhook in runtime?

Comment: pass as variable

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan where?